# Manually installing old version of selenium, missing folder error

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to install an old version of selemenium since the new version seems to have broken my stuff

```
C:\Users\Administrator>python C:\Python33\selenium-2.39.0\setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing top-level names to selenium.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing selenium.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to selenium.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

error: package directory 'py\selenium' does not exist
```

I get that error, and trust me, that folder does most definitely exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make Selenium your working directory

```
cd C:\Python33\selenium-2.39.0
```

And then run `python setup.py install`